# Unable to detect HDD on the new build

Tags: hard-drive, bios, uefi, desktop, desktop-computer

Recently i had built a PC for myself, specs are as follows

```
Ryzen 5 1600 CPU
Asus Prime B350 plus mobo
Samsung EVO 250 GB SATA SSD
Seagate 1 TB HDD
Crucial 8 GB DDR4 RAM
Nvidia GT 1030 GPU
```

Upon first boot to BIOS, i was able to see SSD and HDD along with the pen drive which had windows 10 installation media. I changed the boot order to pen drive to do windows 10 installation. Windows 10 installation was done and SSD, but inside windows environment i was unable to find the seagate HDD.
From disk management there was an uninitialized drive which did not show any space and i was unable to initialize the drive.

Booted back to BIOS, to my surprise HDD was not visible from BIOS as well, of the 6 SATA ports, only SATA 4 showed the SSD. HDD was no where to be found.

What could have happened to HDD during installation, i have also seen some forums where people were advised to disable HDD when windows installation is done to SSD for the first time. Why was this recommended and how do i recover HDD?

Regards,
Ram

Comment: Could you show a screenshot of disk management in Windows?

Comment: @jdwolf Under device manager it reads "Unknown device", under disk management it reads "Uninitialized device" but doesn't allow it to initialize, disk space is also not displayed.

Comment: My BIOS logo time was painfully long 7-80 seconds, so tried disconnecting the HDD connections, BIOS logo disappeared in 3 seconds. Swapped the SSD cables with HDD cables, same issue again. I guess the hard drive was dead shortly after the first time it was recognized. Amazon will be sending the replacement.